# How to say that I need more money?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I want to buy something which costs 10 dollars. I have only 7 dollars.

Now my question is, Which are the other ways to say that I need 3$ more?
Are the sentences below ok?

> 3$ needed more
>
> 3$ more
>
> I lack 3$
>
> 3$ lacked

Comment: In English, we put the dollar sign before the number, like **$3**.

Comment: I lack $3 would work although it does sound a bit strange.

Comment: Note that when writing things out it is generally accepted practice to **spell out** numbers smaller than twelve or so, instead of using the Roman numerals. And of course when you spell out the number you spell out the currency too. So: *I need three more dollars.*

Comment: I'd say, "I want to buy something which costs ten pounds but _I'm three pounds short_." I don't know if I'd find life easy in States! :)

Comment: Or: I need 3 dollars more. Note to Old Brixtonian: we say short in the US, too. three dollars short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would depend on what you are trying to say.

If you wanted to explain that you can't afford it, you might say "Sorry, I'm short by $3", although it would be simpler to just say "Sorry, I only have $7".

If you were a child asking a parent for more money then you might say "I need $3 more", or "I need another $3". Saying "I need..." generally implies that you are trying to get it, so you wouldn't say that unless it was part of a request or some other plan to get it.

Comment: Can I say `the short amount` to refer to the amount that I need?

Comment: The amount that you are short is the balance that you require (amount you need) to purchase the item.

Comment: @MohammadBarbast The phrase is "short by", so "the amount I'm short by" would be what you want, although that is a clumsy way to put it.

Answer (score 1):

If you say

> I need  $3 more.

it is clear that you need  $3 *to complete a sum* that is necessary presumably for a certain purchase.